# Early Stopping Rounds XGBoost in Python

Tags: python, regression, xgboost

I am not understanding why the early stopping rounds function in XGBRegressor does not show the actually best result.

I have read the documentation but I am still confused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So early stopping rounds is basically a function that evaluates whether your loss functions is diminishing or increasing, if it is increasing it is gonna stop your epochs. Meaning, it found the best early parameters that didn't have diminished returns or unwanted returns.
Warning: That does not mean it found your best result, although it will find something pretty close to it.

Why?

Because when your loss functions starts to increase after continuously diminishing, it will enter in some sort of loop stage where it goes back and forward between similar values. The why behind that is MATHs( it envolves diminishing gradient descent returns) But if you keep training maybe you will find a little more precision. Of course depending of the complexity of model, that may not occur. Specially if you formatted a little bit of memory.

Comment: I still do not understand this point. If for example with 15 estimator the rmse is 2.3 why does it arrive until the 20 estimator where the rmse is 2.5 for example. Why does not is stop at the best result? Sorry for bothering you

Comment: What dont you understnad friendorino?

Comment: Most probably, friend. You are not using correctly your early_stopping_rounds function, I would recheck the passed parameters and so on. Unfutanately, I cant help you since I dont have a glimpse of your code

Comment: I have n_estimators = 1000 and early_ stopping_rounds=50. The lowest RMSE is at 13 estimators, but it shows me the results until estimator 63, where the RMSE is higher.Why this?

Comment: You will probably need to reask